# Error running my android app on my device in debug mode

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to ask you about an error running an app in mi device programming in eclipse (ubuntu 12.04).

When I run my app on my `Motorola Defy device` running it on debug mode on eclipse I obtain the following error. The app crashes and shows a `Force Closing Error` in my device.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5919): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.movil.hoja.movihoja.ahmes-1.apk]
```

Somebody knows something about that?

Answer (score 0):

import the jar of android-support-v4 in your eclipse.

Comment: This should be the comment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the ViewPager class from the Android support library. You need to make sure this support library is added to your project.

The following link should provide help on [Adding the Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).